# How do I create a "Recent Activity" Section using PHP and SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, union-all

I am trying to create a recent activity section for a user's profile page. 
For this example, I have 3 tables.

One is the user's table

```
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
:  user_id    :   username   :  join_date  :
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
:     1       :   myacct     :  2018-01-02 :
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
:     2       :   johndoe    :  2018-01-05 :
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Second is the blog_post table

```
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
:    id       :   author_id  :  title      :  content  : post_date :
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
:    1        :      2       :  Some stuff : I like... : 2018-01-05:
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
:    2        :      1       :  My Title   : This i... : 2018-01-04:
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Third is replies

```
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
:    id       :   auth_id    :  headline   : content   : rep_date  :
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
:    1        :      1       :  thanks     : Nice p... : 2018-01-04:
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

What I want to do is grab all from the blog_posts.title column and all from the replies.headline column (grouping the result altogether) where the the author_id and auth_id corresponds to the user_id. Then I want to order it by the dates descending. Note that the date columns for both the blog_posts and the replies table are named differently (as they are in my real circumstance). Then, I want to limit my results by 3 (hence the reason is it "recent" activities).

I have tried using UNION ALL with some success. Although it groups everything from one table, then other tables subsequently follow. In addition, I was confused about fetching it in PHP with a while loop and fetch_object() function

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
SET ROWCOUNT 3
select username, title, post_date, type
from
(
    select username, title, post_date, 'blog post' as "type"
    from blog_post b
    join users u on u.user_id = b.author_id

    union all

    select username, headline as "title", rep_date as "post_date", 'reply' as "type"
    from replies r
    join users u on u.user_id = r.auth_id
) as FullQuery
order by post_date desc
```

Comment: Well, I just gave you the SQL code, not the PHP code.  You probably have issues there too.

Comment: Yes, it appears so.